# Is there a way we can create tests within a loop? So that we create tests based on input data from a file

Tags: robotframework

Would like to hear from you all on a scenario I'm facing. Consider I have three scenarios that I'd like to test and for each scenario, I have about 10 input data which I'd like to Loop and run some tests.

The intention is, for a given scenario, I'd like to see for what range of inputs the test passes and for what it fails. Does this go against the standard of Robot framework test suite practices?

We are testing the results of a Search Engine and hence we expect not all results to pass but rather we are expecting to see when we are getting most ideal results(based on when most of scenarios with data passes).

**Example** :

```
Test -> Scenario 1
       Loop ${line} in File1
              Run Actual Test 1 for Input ${line}

Test -> Scenario 2
       Loop ${line} in File2
              Run Actual Test 2 for Input ${line}

Test -> Scenario 3
       Loop ${line} in File3
              Run Actual Test 3 for Input ${line}
```

Imagine that the files had 5 lines each. The idea is that there would be 15 tests actually and would like to know how many of those 15 pass and how many fail.

Thanks for your help. I'd really appreciate it.

Regards,
Balaji

Answer (score 0):

> Does this go against the standard of Robot framework test suite practices?

It sort of feels like it goes against the idea of actual e2e tests. When you're testing from the perspective of the user, you ideally don't want to ignore any failures.

Having said that, why not run such cases on a different level, perhaps you can tests some endpoints of an API (?)

If you really have to do it in RF, I suppose you can use e.g. [`Run Keyword And Ignore Error` keyword](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Ignore%20Error). It'd not fail any test case but still give you feedback about what data caused a failure.

Answer (score 0):

you can create keywords in place of test scenarios containing the test steps you want to execute for 10 different data. for example:

An excel file containing 10 records and for each record, you want to execute 3 different test scenarios:
[sample code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjhMv.png)